# Assuming I deleted window.alert, how would I get it back?

Tags: javascript

Assume I do this in javascript

```
delete window.alert;
// returns true
```

then the output of `console.log(window.alert);` will be `"undefined"`

There must be a way for code to access the native Functoin that was at `window.alert` originally still, right? 
How would I hence the question **undelete** and restore the window.alert.

Obviously the `window.alert` is only a placeholder for all properties of the global object.

Clarification: I have not "lost" window.alert, but instead I want it to become lost (as for instance to make it unavailable for less trusted code, that then should not have access to `window.alert`. I would assume however there are ways to get the `deleted` functionality back, which I wanted to know about, asking how to "undo" deletion of a property of the global object?)

Comment: Can't you just not delete it in the first place?

Comment: refresh the browser and comment your code you will get back your code. if you want that functionality copy the code for `window.alert` and restore it when you want to undelete it.

Comment: There is no way to recover the function unless you save a reference to it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The use-case would be to find a way to remove some functionality (e.g. `window.alert`) for good, hence the question if it was possible to undo the deletion.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the other answers provoke the impression "there is no getting back deleted objects of window in javascript", as for with my question that was the function of `window.alert`, there is actually a way **without prior backup/copy** to get back deleted properties of the global `window` object.

## get a "virgin" window via injecting an iframe into the DOM

While `window.alert` is gone for `window` we can get ut back by creating another window, or more precisely `contentWindow` via an iframe we inject into the DOM.

```
// step 1 "delete window.alert and check its gone, no backupcopy"
console.log(typeof window.alert); // "function"
delete window.alert;
console.log(typeof window.alert); // "undefined"
try{ window.alert(1); } catch(e){console.log(e);} // TypeError: "window.alert is not a function"

// step 2 "insert an iframe into DOM, to take window.alert from its contentWindow"
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
window.alert = iframe.contentWindow.alert;
console.log(typeof window.alert); // "function"
```

**impact and consequences**

It would seem highly interesting, as a way of a fine-grained disabling of access to certain Javascript and DOM functionality, to simply delete/overwrite those properties. Some form of `"prevent scripts from showing an alert popup"` via `window.alert=function(){}`.
This appealing idea was also some of the motivation to my question. As it rests now, it seems this is not easily possible unless we prevent the loopwhole to regain a "pristine" unmotivied copy of `window` via `iframe.contentWindow`.

The "undelete-via-iframe" trick is based on https://getfastvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test.html, which applied the iframe-regain trick to prevent webrtc functionality removal done "naively" via browser addons

Answer (score 1):

The `window` object is a normal JavaScript object. You can simply "save" the `alert` function by keeping a reference to it.

```
const alert = window.alert;
delete window.alert; // window.alert is now undefined
window.alert = alert;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I have added/updated the question, to some extend my desire is rather to lose the alert for good, and hence seek for ways to recover, from a point at which there is not backup copy.

Comment: No idea why people downvoted  your question so much. I see quite a few use-cases for temporarily deleting built-in `window` functions.

Comment: I assume becaus its somewhat frivolous/naive/provocative phrasing. I would eventually like to more fine-grained then umatrix or noscript limit the access to Browser-Objects in Javascript, by removing them on some sides, to increase/limit/mitigate some attacks on pages that kind of need Javascript to work somewhat in the first place. In the same "security" aspect I also see other examples where benefits from dropping certain Javascript functionality would be nice

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I think the only way without saving it somewhere would be to make a new window with window.open or iframe

Answer (score 1):

> How do you 'undelete' window.alert?

You would have needed to save a reference of the function:

```
var windowAlertBackup = window.alert;
```

And then:

```
window.alert = windowAlertBackup;
```

> What is actually happening?

Any native window function is actually implemented by the javascript interpreter. In javascript window.alert is a pointer to that native function. window.alert is the only default reference to the native window.alert code.