# How to deep clone the window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lodash, clone, deep-copy

I'm trying to clone the window. I used lodash for this. Lodash didn't work, because it brought me empty object. I've tried the methods on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/10004713). None of them worked. How do I clone the window?

```
let w=_.cloneDeep(window);// w={}

//test
console.log(window.console===w.console);
```

Comment: has there been done some modification to the `window` or is it still in pristine "condition"?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I don't know if any changes have been made. I'm using this in the tampermonkey and the site deletes  window functions. for example, console.log does not work. So I'm trying to clone the window.

Comment: I was once interested to "sandbox" (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53666880/1711186) some javascript, by removing some functions. Basically you can get another -potentially "uncircumcised" `window`- via inserting an iframe, which would maybe help you out to have console.log as well?

Comment: sorry the more relevant question was this one [Assuming I deleted window.alert, how would I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48050777/1711186)

Comment: I think it wouldn't be a generic solution. Because dispatchEvent doesn't work and there may be other non-functioning functions that I don't know about. My idea is to clone the window into a variable and then clone it into the window.

Comment: I see :) well I hope you will receive a solution/answer, which I cannot really provide given I do not use tampermonkey and have little insight what it does to provoke your initial problem. I have a feeling that cloning the global object is a challange given that whatever variable you clone it to, has a potential to end up being accessible via the very global object `window` hence it might be a auto/self-reference-circle problem. At best I would do the cloning in the context of a function, as to avoid cloning window to a variable that is part inside of the global `window` itself. good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Hi :) I found the solution.
You should use `cloneDeepWith`.

```
const customizer = (value) => {
 return value
}

let w = _.cloneDeepwith(window, customizer)

console.log(window.console === w.console) // will true
```

Comment: this is wrong answer, `window.console === w.console` should be `false`, if it returns `true` then they are still on the same memory