# Simulating a keyboard event using Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, dispatchevent

I am trying to issue a cntl-b keystroke keyboard event in Firefox to eliminate the sidebar.
Code I am using

```
function assignOnclick()
{
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
evt.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, window,
true, false, false, false,
"b", 0);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The assignOnclick function is called by another function that is executed via the onload on the body statement.
I changed the code to check the boolean return value which is true.
Apparently, Firefox is either ignoring this or I am not doing it correctly.
BTW, entering a cntl-b on the keyboard removes the sidebar.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(  'keydown:' + (e.code ? e.code : e.key));
   
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(  'keyup:' + (e.code ? e.code : e.key));
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
     console.log(  'keypress:' +  (e.code ? e.code : e.key) );
});
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "Control", code : "ControlLeft", ctrlKey : true});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
 e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "B", char : "B", ctrlKey : true});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
 e = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, code : "KeyB", ctrlKey : true});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
 e = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "B", char : "B", ctrlKey : true});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
 e = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {bubbles : true, cancelable : true, key : "Control", code : "ControlLeft", ctrlKey : true});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

if this does not work, the "dispatchEvent" method may be blocked. Look at [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050777/assuming-i-deleted-window-alert-how-would-i-get-it-back) if it doesn't work